# Hibernate mapping and inheritance issues with @SecondaryTable

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm

I have a pretty simple class hierarchy structure that is listed below, each sub class having a @DiscriminatorValue enumeration type, which works very well.

*Abstract class:*

**AbstractNode** (abstract class mapped to the Node table)

*Subclassed classes:*

**FieldNode** (simple class mapped to Node table as well, but with different @DiscriminatorValue value)

**SynonymNode** (problem class, this class also maps to the Node table with a different @DiscriminatorValue value)

but **ALSO** has a @SecondaryTable attribute and has extra columns, such as deletedDate, createdDate, etc... each which map to coumns in the table defined in the @SecondaryTable attribute.

Im issue comes when I do a simple hibernate query for that Node table

I get errors like:

org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
...
stack trace
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name

and in my logs I can see:

Hibernate: 
    Select
        * 
    from
        vocab_node 
    where
        lower(name) like '%' || ? || '%'

INFO  [NullableType.java:132] : could not read column value from result set: DELETED_DATE; Invalid column name

My guess is that it finds a row in the DB table, then identifies that is is a **SynonymNode** class type (by the @DiscriminatorValue column) then tries to populate the class including the extra columns table mapped with the @SecondaryTable.

How can I tell it to either, left join the @SecondaryTable, or exclude it altogether for this particular query?

Thanks heaps! This issue is killing me!

Im running Hibernate 3.2.1, and Java 1.5

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: I should mention that so far my work around is to left join the @SecondaryTable in my SQL so that at least nulls are returned and the mappings are still correct...

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that you have to specify which fields you are mapping to your @SecondaryTable...

In the @Column annotation set the "table" attribute: @Column(name="somecol", table="secondaryTable")

Hibernate is complaining because it is looking for your fields in the original table when it should be looking for them in the secondary table.